# I get an error "The method NewTime(int, int) is undefined for the type NewTime"

Tags: java, eclipse

I get an error once I reach T2.NewTime in the following code.

```
public class NewTimeJUnitTest {

  @Test
  public void testNewTime() // This runs the test using invalid hour value, and valid hour value.
  {
    NewTime T2 = new NewTime(16, 30);               // This contains an invalid value as the minutes. Which leads to the result being invalid.
    T2.subtractTime(03, 00);

    boolean actual = T2.NewTime (hh, mm);
    boolean expected = true;
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no constructor in the class NewTime that takes (int, int) or (Integer, Integer). you simply pass the wrong arguments to the constructor of NewTime.

Comment: NB: don't prefix your time components with zero, as in `00` and `03`. It causes the int literal to be interpreted in octal, meaning you can't write `08` or `09`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor NewTime doesn't have any arguments that match if you call.